# How removing portlet in bootstrap works?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I use bootstrap and when I define a portlet I can use a class named **remove** in my tools to disappear the portlet and I don't know how bootstrap does it.

Here is my code:

```
<!-- BEGIN ROW -->
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <!-- BEGIN PORTLET-->
    <div class="portlet light bordered">
        <div class="portlet-title">
            <div class="tools">
                <a class="remove" > </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="portlet-body">

        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END PORTLET-->
</div>
</div>
<!-- END ROW -->
```

You can see an example of this functionality in the below link:
http://keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/admin_6/portlet_ajax.html

Comment: Whats the problem actually? Be clear and specific.

Comment: @roxid As I said I don't know how this process works. What happens when I click the remove button and which function is responsible for removing the portlet from the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code which remove the portlet.

```
$('body').on('click', '.portlet > .portlet-title > .tools > a.remove', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var portlet = $(this).closest(".portlet");

            if ($('body').hasClass('page-portlet-fullscreen')) {
                $('body').removeClass('page-portlet-fullscreen');
            }

            portlet.find('.portlet-title .fullscreen').tooltip('destroy');
            portlet.find('.portlet-title > .tools > .reload').tooltip('destroy');
            portlet.find('.portlet-title > .tools > .remove').tooltip('destroy');
            portlet.find('.portlet-title > .tools > .config').tooltip('destroy');
            portlet.find('.portlet-title > .tools > .collapse, .portlet > .portlet-title > .tools > .expand').tooltip('destroy');

            portlet.remove();
        });
```

Comment: Thank you. In which file did you find it?